Retrieve installed plugin in Shopware
I currently retrieve if a plugin is installed like this:
$adyenPlugin = $this->pluginRepository->search(
    (new Criteria())->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('name', self::ADYEN_PAYMENT_PLUGIN_NAME)),
    Context::createDefaultContext(),
)->first();
if (!$adyenPlugin || null === $adyenPlugin->get('installedAt')) {
    return new TableCollection(...$tables);
}


What would be the default way in Shopware to check if a plugin is installed? I would assume Shopware has a helper function or something?

It does work. But I am wondering if Shopware has a default helper function or something to check if a plugin is installed? Edit: I edited my question to ask specifically for the default way in Shopware, making it non-opinionated.

You can inject the Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin\KernelPluginLoader\KernelPluginLoader.
Then you can check if a plugin is active like this:
$pluginData = $this->pluginLoader->getPluginInstance('Adyen\Shopware\AdyenPaymentShopware6');
if (!$pluginData || !$pluginData->isActive()) {
    return;
}

// Your logic

Is there a reason you want to check if a plugin is installed instead of active? An installed plugin won't execute any code / logic in Shopware.

Thanks for the answer. Seems to work. And I only want to know if it's installed because if it's installed, tables need to be cleared. No matter if it's active or not. My code is a plugin for developers/testing. Not for production.
